# How to loop though PHP data to create a thumbnail carousel in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: php, loops, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let me try and explain myself, but my code below will probably do most of the talking. I want to loop through my data and insert a "row" div for every 6 images that are looped through. You can see from my code below how I am currently achieving this, but I know there is a better way.

I need to either check the loop in multiples of 6 to echo "row" and multiples of 6-1 (5, 11, etc) to echo the closing div tag, or is there way I can change my data into a collection of arrays containing 4 thumbnails each?

I will let the code do the talking now (I am using blade templating with laravel).

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php 
        $i = 0; 
        $templatesInView = 6; ?>

        @foreach ($templates as $template)

            @if($i == 0 || $i % $templatesInView == 0)
                <div class="row item @if($i==0){{{ 'active' }}}@endif">
            @endif

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="{{{ asset($template->img) }}}" />
            </div>

            @if($i == 5 || $i == 11 || $i == 17 || $i == 15 || $i == (count($templates)-1))
                 </div>
            @endif
            <?php $i++; ?>

        @endforeach
    </div>
```

Edit - OK, I have just found array_chunk() which does exactly what I need, but it would be good to hear if there are any other alternatives.

Comment: You basically want to have only 6 images in a row, correct?

Comment: Yes, every six images I want to a container "row" div. Splitting my original array into chunks of 6 using array_chunk now seems like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways of adding pages to a 'list' of things stored in an 'array' is to use the **array_group_by_n** function. This takes any array and using 'callbacks' will call functions at the appropriate times.

I supply some **tested code** that demonstrates this. It is based on your code.

I use PHP 5.3.18

The code generates a random number of 'images' (MyImage class) and then displays them in 'pages' of up to 6, as you request.

```
<?php session_start();

/*
 * Using an array function called:
 *   array_group_by_n
 */

include 'function_array_group_by_n.php';


// ================ global data -- Only things you need to change ===========
$templates = array();         // array of images == you supply this

$templatesInView = 6;         // max number of templates in the view

// --------------- end of stuff that you need to change -----------------------

// functions called by function array_group_by_n

// function to call at Group start
$beforeGroupStart =
    function($firstRow) {
        echo '<div class="row item"> <!-- start of template group -->';
        echo "<p>Template Group Start: {$firstRow->getName()}</p>";
    };

// function to call for every record in a group
$inGroup =
    function($row, $rowNumber) {
        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
        echo '<p>LineNumber: ', $rowNumber, ' : img source: ',  $row->getName(), '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    };


// function to call at Group End
$afterGroupEnd =
    function() {
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<p>Template Group End</p>';
    };

// include 'Q22683444_test_data_setup.php';
// generateTestData(); // i need this
?>


<!-- --------------- style the output so you can see what is happening -------- -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Paging an Array</title>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
         .row  {
             background-color: yellow;
             border: 4px solid green;
             padding: 5px;
             margin-top: 5px;
         }

         p {color: blue;}

         .col-sm-2 {
             background-color: white;
             border: 2px solid red;
             padding: 3px;
         }

         .carousel-inner {
             background-color: grey;
             border: 4px solid blue;
             padding: 5px;
             margin-top: 5px;
         }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Random Template count is: <?php echo count($templates); ?></h2>

<div class="carousel-inner"> <!-- carousel start -->
<?php
  // now process the array details...

  $totalRows = array_group_by_n($templates, $templatesInView,
                                /* callable */ $beforeGroupStart,
                                /* callable */ $inGroup,
                                /* callable */ $afterGroupEnd
                   );
?>
  </div> <!-- carousel end -->
  <?php echo '<br />', "Total Images Processed was: ${totalRows}"  ,'<br />'; ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php exit; // leave script ?>
<!-- ------------------ end of the processing ------------------------ -->
```

Obviously, you need the 'array_group_by_n' function details:

```
<?php
/*
 * function: array_group_by_n
 *
 * Use: iterates over an array and calls user functions as explained below 
 *           
 * parameters:
 *
 * 1) array:    the array to be grouped
 *
 * 2) integer:  size of each group
 *
 * there are three 'callable' routines required
 *
 * a)  before the group starts
 *     parameter passed: the first record of the group -- DO NOT PRINT IT!
 *                       Use the contents if you have, say, title information
 *                       in it.
 *
 * b) each row in the group
 *    parameters passed:  1) the value of the current array entry
 *                        2) the group entry number - zero based
 *
 * c)  after the current group ends
 *     parameter passed: none
 *
 * @returns integer - count of rows processed
 */

function array_group_by_n(array $data = array(), $groupSize = 0,
                         /* callable */ $beforeGroup = null,
                         /* callable */ $inGroup = null,
                         /* callable */ $afterGroup = null)
{
    $theIterator = new ArrayIterator($data);

    $processedRows  = 0;
    $currentEntryNo = 0;

    while ($theIterator->valid()) { // process the array

        // start of group...
        if ($groupSize >= 1) { // only called if required...
            if (is_callable($beforeGroup)) { // and is valid routine
                call_user_func($beforeGroup, $theIterator->current());
            }
        }

        // initialize the current group
        $currentEntryNo = 0;

        /*
         * process the group body
         */
        do {

            if (is_callable($inGroup)) { // is valid routine
                call_user_func($inGroup,
                               $theIterator->current(),
                               $currentEntryNo);
            }

            $currentEntryNo++;
            $processedRows++;

            $theIterator->next(); // next entry or end of array
        }
        while ($theIterator->valid() && $currentEntryNo < $groupSize);


        // end of group...
        if ($groupSize >= 1) { // only called if required...
            if (is_callable($afterGroup)) { // and is valid routine
                call_user_func($afterGroup);
            }
        }
    }
    // all done -- go home

    return $processedRows;
}
?>
```

For completeness i include the 'test generator' script.

```
<?php // ----------------- my test data -- ignore this --------------------
// test class - holds an 'image description'
class MyImage {
  private $imageName = '';

  public function __construct($imageIdx) {
      $this->imageName = 'i am image with index: '. $imageIdx;
  }

  public function getName() {
      return $this->imageName;
  }
}

function generateTestData()
{
   global $templates;
   // ------------------------- start of test data --------------------------------
   //
   // test data -- array of image descriptions -- ensure count is defferent on each run
  if (!isset($_SESSION['prevCount'])) {
      $_SESSION['prevCount'] = -1;
  }

  do {
      $randomCount = mt_rand(1, 20);
  }
  while ($randomCount == $_SESSION['prevCount']);

  for ($i = 0;  $i < $randomCount; $i++) { // fill $templates with test images
      $templates[] = new MyImage($i);
  }
  // ------------------------- end of test data ----------------------------------
}
?>
```